# Fill in missing dates based on min and max in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset like the one below, I am wondering how can i fill in those missing dates in SAS.

1. Missing FROM_NEW (2nd line)

   First, find the TO_NEW (14NOV2016) in the last row of TOS="FAC_IP" under the same ADM. 
    Then, loop in PRO_IP to find the min(date) but greater than (>14NOV2016) to replace the missing FROM_NEW which is **20NOV2016** should be filled in.
2. Missing TO_NEW (line 25)

   First, find the FROM_NEW (14DEC2016) in the last row of TOS="FAC_IP"
    Then, loop in PRO_IP to find the max(date) but less than (<14DEC2016) to replace the missing TO_NEW which **08DEC2016** should be filled in.

   ```
   Obs     MEMNUM       ADM    LINE   FROM      TO     FROM_NEW   TO_NEW   TOS  order 
   1  9840964190000001 237696870 X 23OCT2016 23NOV2016 23OCT2016 30OCT2016 FAC_IP 1 
   2  9840964190000001 237696870 R 23OCT2016 23NOV2016 .         23NOV2016 FAC_IP 2 
   3  9840964190000001 237696870 X 23OCT2016 23NOV2016 02NOV2016 03NOV2016 FAC_IP 3 
   4  9840964190000001 237696870 X 23OCT2016 23NOV2016 05NOV2016 09NOV2016 FAC_IP 4 
   5  9840964190000001 237696870 X 23OCT2016 23NOV2016 11NOV2016 14NOV2016 FAC_IP 5 
   6  9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 25OCT2016 25OCT2016 PRO_IP . 
   7  9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 26OCT2016 26OCT2016 PRO_IP . 
   8  9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 27OCT2016 27OCT2016 PRO_IP . 
   9  9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 28OCT2016 28OCT2016 PRO_IP . 
   10 9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 29OCT2016 29OCT2016 PRO_IP . 
   11 9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 30OCT2016 30OCT2016 PRO_IP . 
   12 9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 02NOV2016 02NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
   13 9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 03NOV2016 03NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
   14 9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 06NOV2016 06NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
   15 9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 07NOV2016 07NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
   16 9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 08NOV2016 08NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
   17 9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 11NOV2016 11NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
   18 9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 12NOV2016 12NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
   19 9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 13NOV2016 13NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
   20 9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 14NOV2016 14NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
   21 9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 20NOV2016 20NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
   22 9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 21NOV2016 21NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
   23 9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 22NOV2016 22NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
   24 9840964190000001 237696870   23OCT2016 23NOV2016 23NOV2016 23NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
   25 9840964190000001 244243815 R 04DEC2016 17DEC2016 04DEC2016 .         FAC_IP 1 
   26 9840964190000001 244243815 X 04DEC2016 17DEC2016 14DEC2016 17DEC2016 FAC_IP 2 
   27 9840964190000001 244243815   04DEC2016 17DEC2016 04DEC2016 04DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
   28 9840964190000001 244243815   04DEC2016 17DEC2016 05DEC2016 05DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
   29 9840964190000001 244243815   04DEC2016 17DEC2016 06DEC2016 06DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
   30 9840964190000001 244243815   04DEC2016 17DEC2016 07DEC2016 07DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
   31 9840964190000001 244243815   04DEC2016 17DEC2016 08DEC2016 08DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
   32 9840964190000001 244243815   04DEC2016 17DEC2016 14DEC2016 14DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
   33 9840964190000001 244243815   04DEC2016 17DEC2016 15DEC2016 15DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
   34 9840964190000001 244243815   04DEC2016 17DEC2016 16DEC2016 16DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
   35 9840964190000001 244243815   04DEC2016 17DEC2016 17DEC2016 17DEC2016 PRO_IP .
   ```

Comment: This is not an easy task. To improve your chances of getting an answer, please provide a reproducible example (including the code necessary to generate your sample data which should be free of unnecessary columns), as well as things you might have tried so far, or ideas you might have about solving this.

Comment: not so hard, see below

Answer (score 0):

so, here's how you can update the FROM_NEW in a sas macro.  It's pretty explicit and you should be able to create your own macro to do the TO_NEW.  If you need additional help come back with what you've tried and we can go from there.  Make sure all your dates are actual sas dates and not literals in your dataset

```
*create file of all needed from_new dates
proc sql noprint;
create table needed_FN as
select distinct adm,order as row from test where from_new = .;quit;

* find out how many we have
proc sql noprint;
select count(*) into: cnt from needed_fn;quit;

*create macro to loop through
%macro test;
%do i = 1 %to &cnt;

   *for each needed from_new date place the adm and order number into macro vars
   proc sql noprint;
    select ADM,row into: adm, :row  from needed_FN where monotonic()=&i;quit;

   * create temp table for specific adm
   proc sql noprint;
    create table work as 
     select * from test where adm = &adm;quit;

   * find out how many 'FAC_IP's we have
   proc sql noprint;
    select max(order)into:maxOrder from work;quit;

   * get the checkdate
   proc sql noprint;
    select (TO_NEW) format=date9. into:checkDate  from work where ORDER= &maxOrder;

   *create temp table of all PRO_iP dates > checkDate
   proc sql noprint;
    create table proDates as
     select * from work where TOS='PRO_IP' and FROM_NEW > "&checkDate"d;quit;

   * get the smallest one
   proc sql noprint;
    select min(From_new)format date9. into:replaceDate from prodates;quit;

   *update the table
   proc sql;
    update test
      set from_new = "&replaceDate"d
          where adm = &adm
          and order = &row;   
%end;
%mend test;
%test;
```

Comment: Thanks DCR. It didn't go through from my end. I will play it again next week. Again, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use either  nested sub-queries or use the SAS `Retain` functionality within a data step to accomplish this.

Solution below is using sub-queries, see my inline comments:

```
data have;
/* infile datalines dlm=',' dsd;  */
length Obs 8.    MEMNUM  $22.     ADM  $9.  LINE $1.   FROM   8.     TO   8.    FROM_NEW 8.    TO_NEW  8.   TOS $6. order  8. ;
format FROM   date9.     TO   date9.    FROM_NEW  date9.    TO_NEW  date9. ;
informat FROM   date9.     TO   date9.    FROM_NEW  date9.    TO_NEW  date9. ;
input 
Obs     MEMNUM  $     ADM  $  LINE $   FROM      TO     FROM_NEW   TO_NEW   TOS $ order ;
datalines; 
1  9840964190000001 237696870 X 23OCT2016 23NOV2016 23OCT2016 30OCT2016 FAC_IP 1 
2  9840964190000001 237696870 R 23OCT2016 23NOV2016 .         23NOV2016 FAC_IP 2 
3  9840964190000001 237696870 X 23OCT2016 23NOV2016 02NOV2016 03NOV2016 FAC_IP 3 
4  9840964190000001 237696870 X 23OCT2016 23NOV2016 05NOV2016 09NOV2016 FAC_IP 4 
5  9840964190000001 237696870 X 23OCT2016 23NOV2016 11NOV2016 14NOV2016 FAC_IP 5 
6  9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 25OCT2016 25OCT2016 PRO_IP . 
7  9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 26OCT2016 26OCT2016 PRO_IP . 
8  9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 27OCT2016 27OCT2016 PRO_IP . 
9  9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 28OCT2016 28OCT2016 PRO_IP . 
10 9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 29OCT2016 29OCT2016 PRO_IP . 
11 9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 30OCT2016 30OCT2016 PRO_IP . 
12 9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 02NOV2016 02NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
13 9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 03NOV2016 03NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
14 9840964190000001 237696870 . 23OCT2016 23NOV2016 06NOV2016 06NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
15 9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 07NOV2016 07NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
16 9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 08NOV2016 08NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
17 9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 11NOV2016 11NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
18 9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 12NOV2016 12NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
19 9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 13NOV2016 13NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
20 9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 14NOV2016 14NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
21 9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 20NOV2016 20NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
22 9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 21NOV2016 21NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
23 9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 22NOV2016 22NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
24 9840964190000001 237696870 .  23OCT2016 23NOV2016 23NOV2016 23NOV2016 PRO_IP . 
25 9840964190000001 244243815 R 04DEC2016 17DEC2016 04DEC2016 .         FAC_IP 1 
26 9840964190000001 244243815 X 04DEC2016 17DEC2016 14DEC2016 17DEC2016 FAC_IP 2 
27 9840964190000001 244243815 .  04DEC2016 17DEC2016 04DEC2016 04DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
28 9840964190000001 244243815 .  04DEC2016 17DEC2016 05DEC2016 05DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
29 9840964190000001 244243815 .  04DEC2016 17DEC2016 06DEC2016 06DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
30 9840964190000001 244243815 .  04DEC2016 17DEC2016 07DEC2016 07DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
31 9840964190000001 244243815 .  04DEC2016 17DEC2016 08DEC2016 08DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
32 9840964190000001 244243815 .  04DEC2016 17DEC2016 14DEC2016 14DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
33 9840964190000001 244243815 .  04DEC2016 17DEC2016 15DEC2016 15DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
34 9840964190000001 244243815 .  04DEC2016 17DEC2016 16DEC2016 16DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
35 9840964190000001 244243815 .  04DEC2016 17DEC2016 17DEC2016 17DEC2016 PRO_IP . 
;
run;
proc sql; 
create table  missing_dates as
select MEMNUM , ADM , FROM_NEW , TO_NEW , MAX_FROM_NEW , Max_TO_NEW ,
max(FNL)  as FNL format=date9., min(TNL) as TNL format=date9. 
from (
    select t1.*, t2.Max_Order, t3.FROM_NEW as MAX_FROM_NEW , t3.TO_NEW as Max_TO_NEW ,
    t4.FROM_NEW as FNL, t4.TO_NEW as TNL
    from 
/*  Identify Missing dates*/
    (select * from have where FROM_NEW = . or TO_NEW=.) as t1
    left join 
/*  Identify Max order */
    (select MEMNUM, ADM, max(order)  as Max_Order 
    from have where TOS='FAC_IP' group by MEMNUM, ADM ) as t2 on t1.MEMNUM=t2.MEMNUM and t1.ADM = t2.ADM
/*  Join Max Order with the rest of the Data */
    inner join have as t3 on t3.TOS='FAC_IP' and t3.MEMNUM=t2.MEMNUM and t3.ADM = t2.ADM and t3.order=t2.Max_Order
/*  Join Max Order with PRO_IP */
    left join
    (select  MEMNUM, ADM, FROM_NEW , TO_NEW from have where TOS='PRO_IP' group by MEMNUM, ADM ) as t4 on t1.MEMNUM=t4.MEMNUM and t1.ADM = t4.ADM
) as want 
where case when (FROM_NEW=. and TNL> Max_TO_NEW) then 1
when (TO_NEW=. and FNL  < MAX_FROM_NEW) then 1
else 0
end
group by MEMNUM , ADM , FROM_NEW , TO_NEW , MAX_FROM_NEW , Max_TO_NEW  
; 
quit;

proc sql;
 create table update_mising as select 
A.Obs, A.MEMNUM, A.ADM  , A.LINE ,A.FROM , A.TO   , 
coalesce(A.FROM_NEW,B.TNL) as FROM_NEW format=date9.  , 
coalesce(A.TO_NEW,B.TNL) as TO_NEW format=date9. ,
 A.TOS , A.order 
from have  A left join missing_dates B
on (A.FROM_NEW = . or A.TO_NEW=.) and A.MEMNUM=B.MEMNUM and A.ADM = B.ADM
order by A.OBS
;
quit;
```

Final Table:

[image: Output]

Comment: Let me know if  need any clarification or further help.

Comment: Thanks momo1644. Yes. it works majority of my dataset if modified the statement coalesce(A.TO_NEW,**B.TNL**) as TO_NEW format=date9.   as coalesce(A.TO_NEW,**B.FNL**) as TO_NEW format=date9. , but still has some datasets not be filled in. I will put  here later if my way doesn't work. Thanks so much!